# Adafruit BLE sniffer using subprocess error

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been trying to use subprocess to alternate between reading from different BLE devices in a script with the Bluefruit LE sniffer. I am using the sniffer Python API on a Raspberry Pi 3. This is the code written so far:

```
import os
import time
import serial
from subprocess import Popen, run, PIPE

command = ['sudo', 'python', 'Adafruit_BLESniffer_Python/sniffer.py', '/dev/ttyUSB0', '-t DC:0D:33:A7:11:3E']
ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyUSB0") #used for readlines

process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
out, err = process.communicate()
print(out,err)
```

However, I receive the following error when running:

```
Capturing data to logs/capture.pcap
Connecting to sniffer on /dev/ttyUSB0
specified target device DC:0D:33:A7:11:3E
Attempting to follow device DC:0D:33:A7:11:3E
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Adafruit_BLESniffer_Python/sniffer.py", line 202, in <module>
mySniffer.follow(d)
File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BLESniffer_Python/SnifferAPI/Sniffer.py", line 50, in follow
self._startFollowing(device, followOnlyAdvertisements)
File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BLESniffer_Python/SnifferAPI/SnifferCollector.py", line 223, in _startFollowing
device.address, device.txAdd, followOnlyAdvertisements)
File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BLESniffer_Python/SnifferAPI/Packet.py", line 206, in sendFollow
self.sendPacket(REQ_FOLLOW, addr+[followOnlyAdvertisements], timeout)
File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BLESniffer_Python/SnifferAPI/Packet.py", line 198, in sendPacket
self.uart.writeList(pkt, timeout)
File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BLESniffer_Python/SnifferAPI/UART.py", line 77, in writeList
nBytes = self.ser.write(array)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 531, in write
raise portNotOpenError
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open
```

The command "sudo python Adafruit_BLESniffer_Python/sniffer.py /dev/ttyUSB0 -t " works without error in the terminal. Also, the output only prints when sniffing certain devices and sometimes needs the terminal open on the "select a device to sniff" menu. Are there any ideas as to what could be the cause of the issue? I believe that it is most likely a problem with connecting to the BLE device or retrieving data from it with the sniffer.

Comment: You have already opened `/dev/yyuUSB0` in your wrapper, so the subprocess can't open it.  Serial ports are one-at-a-time. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I'm sort of new to subprocess. Is this happening because this program is connecting to the port while sniffer.py is trying to read and write data?

Comment: Right.  Your code is opening `/dev/ttyUSB0` just before launching the process, and that prevents the process from opening it.  WHY is your code opening the serial port?  You aren't using it.

Comment: I added it later on to try and use readlines to troubleshoot. I modified a copy of the sniffer.py file to do the loop in there and it worked. Thanks for your help!